# Daily Average Sales for items in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Based on order history, I'm trying to calculate the daily average sales for a given product form a vendor.

I have a table containing the line-item detail for the sales order. The relevant columns are:

item_id, vendor_id, ship_qty, post_date

I want to get a daily total of product sales for a given item. Item id's can be duplicated across vendors, but not within the same vendor id.  With that total I'm trying to derive the average quantity sold per day.

I started by creating a view that provides the sum by item on a given day:

```
daily_sales_by_item as SELECT  SUM(ship_qty) 
AS item_total, item_id,vendor_id, post_date FROM order_history
GROUP BY vendor_id, item_id, post_date
```

Then I'm selecting an average from this view and grouping by the vendor_id and item_id as a sub-query:

```
SELECT item_id,vendor_id from daily_sales_by_item 
d where d.item_id = o.item_id and d.vendor_id = o.vendor_id
```

I feel like I must be way of using this approach, because the numbers I'm getting are totally inaccurate.

Any help is greatly appricated.

Comment: your first sql looks fine, but the second seems to be cut off somewhere. It references 'o', but there is not table named o in the query. Probably just a cut and paste issue. You may want to edit it and repost.

Comment: Perhaps AVG instead of SUM?  What is the datatype of `post_date`?